# Make single array from items in inner arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

Please consider following:

```
struct House {
  let houseName: String
  let personIn: [Person]
}

struct Person {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}

var persons: [Person] = [ Person(name: "pers1", age: 10),
                          Person(name: "pers2", age: 20),
                          Person(name: "pers3", age: 30)]

var houses: [House] = [House(houseName: "houseNameFirst", personIn: persons),
                       House(houseName: "houseNameSecond", personIn: persons),
                       House(houseName: "houseNameThird", personIn: persons)]

let names = houses.map{ $0.personIn.map{$0.name}}
print(names) // Prints  [["pers1", "pers2", "pers3"], ["pers1", "pers2", "pers3"], ["pers1", "pers2", "pers3"]]
```

I want an array of just Person names, instead of array of arrays, is there short way to achieve that without making an extension to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `flatMap(_:)` function on `houses` array:

```
let names = houses.flatMap { $0.personIn.map{ $0.name } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.2 or later you can use keypath to flatten your collection then you can simply map the name

```
let names = houses.flatMap(\.personIn).map(\.name)
```